# Samsung Chronos 7 unable to boot up after installing Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, windows-8, laptop

I just bought a new laptop Samsung Chronos 7. I have wipe the Windows 8 and recovery partition off from the SSD.

I installed Windows 7 on the laptop, however upon starting up. The laptop keeps restarting itself.

My bios option:
Secure Boot: Off
OS Mode Selection: CSM OS

Fast BIOS Mode: Off
AHCI Mode Control: Manual
-Set AHCI Mode: On

Comment: What Series 7 Chronos is it? Do you have the exact model number?

Comment: @ConnDarcy np730u3e

Comment: Sice it came with a pre-installed windows 8, I guess it has something to do with secure boot.  
Did you check that in the BIOS? Does it boot in Legacy mode or UEFI mode?  
Do you know if your SSD is partitioned as GPT or MBR?

Comment: @Ali I have turn off secure boot and boot using CSM but still failed. I am not sure what is GPT or MBR?

Comment: Secure Boot: Off
OS Mode Selection: CSM OS

Fast BIOS Mode: Off
AHCI Mode Control: Manual
-Set AHCI Mode: On

Comment: Could please specify the model number?